# How do I count instances of a categorical variable for each instance of another categorical variable?

Tags: r

Disclaimer: I can't include data because it's confidential student data.

I have an R dataframe "data" with a column "StateResidence" for what state the student is from, and a column "Enrolled" 0 or a 1 that tells whether or not they enrolled in the school I go to.

I'm trying to make a dataframe with three columns: Column 1 should list out each of the 69 unique States listed in Data (I've already done this one), and column 2 should show how many students from that state are enrolled, and column 3 should show what percentage of the total students from that state were enrolled.

The reason for this is so I can do some exploratory data analysis by plotting barplots with the number on the Y axis and the state on the X axis to analyze enrollment trends geographically.

I really don't have much else to include - I'm completely lost here, and I'm not very familiar with R. Any help is greatly appreciated, even just some helpful functions or something. Thank you.

Comment: "Disclaimer: I can't include data because it's confidential student data."  You'll get a better response if you take the time to generate some mock data rather than expecting users to do the work for you.

Comment: Ritchie, thanks for taking the time to comment. I don't see why any data is needed, since I just need to know the functions/process that might get me to where I need to go. "Expecting users to do the work for me" was far from the goal.